# Where can I find free Bathymetric data for Indian Ocean?

Tags: data, visualisation, bathymetry, indian-ocean

I am looking for bathymetric data, to place in a map of India for visualization only.

I don't really need very high resolution data, since the the map will be at a very small scale: Maybe 1:1Million or 1:5,00,000.

Which are the sources that I can freely use?

Comment: are we looking for contour bathymetry or just ocean bottom?  Try this if the latter... http://blogs.esri.com/info/blogs/esri-insider/archive/2011/06/30/try-our-new-ocean-basemap.aspx

Comment: @BradNesom: This is a really good map source. Can you please put your comment as a answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ocean bottom basemap (no contours).
I recently noticed the ocean basemap release.
[arcgisonline ocean](http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer) (rest endpoint)
There are some pointers for using it with other basemap extents and
also, more information and several other good links for oceanic data
(including disputed maritime boundaries) on the esri blog archives.
[Esri blog](http://blogs.esri.com/info/blogs/esri-insider/archive/2011/06/30/try-our-new-ocean-basemap.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/ has 1:50M rasters of the Ocean Bottom (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/). All their data is public domain so there are no worries about licenses.

Answer (score 4):

[CleanTopo2](http://www.shadedrelief.com/cleantopo2/index.html) looks promising, and is public domain.

> CleanTOPO2 is a touched up and generalized version of SRTM30 Plus, a public domain dataset that combines sea floor and land elevation data of the entire world.
>
> CleanTOPO2 comes in three versions tailored to meet different design and production needs. All versions are 16-bit grayscale TIF files measuring 10,800 x 5,400-pixels and include a World (.tfw) file and "Read me" document with projection and datum information. The Geographic projection is used. All data available here are in the public domain.

Answer (score 3):

The NOAA has an extensive collection of [bathymetric data sources](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/relief.html). I assume you are referring to bathymetric *ocean* data?

Comment: yes, I am referring to ocean depth data

Comment: For the scale that you are using I would suggest the [ETOPO1 Dataset](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html).

Comment: +1 I followed the link and was pleased to find [NOAA's Bathymetry Viewer](http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/bathymetry/).

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been suggested, [NOAA](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/relief.html) has one of the best databases for data, a specialised one. Also, I'd recommend [GEBCO](http://www.gebco.net/), from their data you can actually create pretty decent maps (I did for the Black Sea as an example).